# ASP.NET SQL Server Sessions and deployment

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, deployment

I just deployed my first ASP.NET App to server and everything would be fine if not problems with database... I have sessions stored in SQL Server as two tables. Those tables are operated thru stored procedures. When deploying app I have moved database by making a backup copy of my local db and uploading it to production server. This caused that names were mixed and stored procedures were not working.

Is there a way to deploy database witch changed names ?! Or every time I deploy application to server I need to run asp's create-session-in-db app ?!

Comment: Is it the names of your databases that is causing the issue, or the names of your two tables?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to deploy the database using SQL scripts then backup/restore or copy. You can tailor the scripts to your specific need at the time, eg. alter, drop/create. You also get a record of what your data structures are that can be filed with your app.

Simon